# Receiving Events in Vue3 - Property was accessed during render but is not defined on instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, events

Beginner to Vue and JavaScript - but learning ))

I have a Vue Mains App, and a sub-component handling a form (Calculate the difference between 2 values).

I wish the values of the form to be reset to the initial value when the mains App "Reset" button is clicked.

I have 2 problems:

- the page reloads when I click on the form button "Calculate Difference"
- the "Reset" is not resetting the initial value - it seems the event is not distributed to the sub-component.

On loading the page I have the following warning that I can't interpret:

[Vue warn]: Property "reset" was accessed during render but is not defined on the instance. at

Here is the all in one-page sample code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Difference</title>
  <script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <div id="app">

    <br> Change Values, Click "Calculate Difference", then "Reset" to set Back to 0
    <br>
    <calculator v-on:reset="reset" :start_val="0" :end_val="0"> </calculator>
    <br>
    <button class="button" v-on:click="onResetButton()"> Reset </button>

  </div>
</body>

<script>
  const vm = Vue.createApp({
    emits: {
      'reset': null
    },
    methods: {
      onResetButton() {
        console.log("onResetButton $emit")
        this.$emit('reset');
      },
    },
  })

  vm.component('calculator', {
    props: ['start_val', 'end_val'],
    data() {
      return {
        calculator: {
          start_val: this.start_val,
          end_val: this.end_val,
          difference: this.end_val - this.start_val,
        },
      }
    },
    methods: {
      onDifference() {
        console.log("onDifference")
        this.calculator.difference = this.calculator.end_val - this.calculator.start_val
        console.log(this.calculator.difference)
      },
      reset() {
        calculator.start_val = this.start_val
        calculator.end_val = this.end_val
        calculator.difference = this.end_val - this.start_val
        console.log("reset calculator")
      }
    },
    template: `
            <hr>
            <form>
                <br> Start Value : <input class="input" type="number"  v-model.number="calculator.start_val">
                <br> End Value   : <input class="input" type="number"  v-model.number="calculator.end_val">
                <br> <button class="button" v-on:click="onDifference()">Calculate Difference  </button>
            </form>
            <p>Difference : {{ calculator.difference }} </p>
            <hr>
  `
  })

  vm.mount('#app');
</script>

</html>
```

Comment: There's no `reset` in `vm`. That you defined it inside `calculator` can't affect what happens outside the component.

Comment: Added a reset in vm (not sure how this is working for serving the purpose of the event sharing).  methods : {  reset() {   console.log("reset")  },
Gives me the following error:
vue@next:7996 [Vue warn]: Extraneous non-emits event listeners (reset) were passed to component but could not be automatically inherited because component renders fragment or text root nodes. If the listener is intended to be a component custom event listener only, declare it using the "emits" option. 
  at <Calculator onReset=fn<bound reset> start_val=0 end_val=0 > 
  at <App>

Comment: It's `calculator` that emits `reset` *event* and should have `emits: ['reset']`. It's `vm` instance that should have `reset` *method*. That you have logic in `vm` and not a component is not very common. Consider figuring out the relation between components and their props/events with parent and child comp instead, it's more common and covered in examples.

Comment: This code is the simplification of a much bigger application - with a dozen of sub-components. When the vm top component receives new data, I need the sub components to refresh with new values (instead of a reset, the real app sends update with payload, but I remove the update as a matter of simplifying to event passing) - hence the (maybe inappropriate sample) logic here.

Comment: I see. You have a basic problem with component and prop relation, I'd suggest to figure it out in a simplified setup that doesn't involve more exotic things like providing a template as children of root element (`<div id="app">`)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a small snippet that probably gives you ideas:

```js
const {
  reactive,
  ref,
  toRefs,
  computed
} = Vue

const Calculator = {
  props: {
    startVal: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
    endVal: {
      type: Number,
      default: 0,
    },
  },
  emits: ['update:startVal', 'update:endVal'],
  setup(props, {
    emit
  }) {
    const start_val = computed({
      get() {
        return props.startVal
      },
      set(val) {
        emit('update:startVal', val || 0)
      },
    })
    const end_val = computed({
      get() {
        return props.endVal
      },
      set(val) {
        emit('update:endVal', val || 0)
      },
    })
    return {
      start_val,
      end_val
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      {{ start_val }} / {{ end_val }}<br />
      StartVal: <input v-model.number="start_val" /><br />
      EndVal: <input v-model.number="end_val" />
    </div>
  `
}

const initState = () => ({
  startVal: 0,
  endVal: 0
})

const App = {
  setup() {
    const state = reactive(initState())

    const result = computed(() => {
      return state.startVal + state.endVal
    })

    const resetState = () => {
      const defaultState = initState()
      for (let key in state) {
        state[key] = defaultState[key]
      }
    }

    return {
      result,
      ...toRefs(state),
      resetState,
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      Result: {{ result }}<br />
      <button
        @click="resetState"
      >
        RESET
      </button>
      <Calculator
        v-model:startVal="startVal"
        v-model:endVal="endVal"
      />
    </div>
  `
}

const vm = Vue
  .createApp(App)

vm.component('Calculator', Calculator)

vm.mount('#app')
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue@next"></script>

<div id="app"></div>
```